# How to set missing elements from the result in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, array, wire

If the following array is the result from the database as input to datatable in LWC. How can I set empty/missing elements which are empty (fields are optional)? Datatable is showing as empty because of missing columns in the result. I assume that adding missing elements will resolve my issue. Any idea?

```
 [
  {
    "Integration_Status__c": "Pending",
    "Consumed_Date__c": "2022-04-21T12:17:38.000Z",
    "Id": "1"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2"
  },
  {
    "Id": "3"
  },
  {
    "Integration_Status__c": "Pending",
    "Consumed_Date__c": "2022-04-21T12:15:28.000Z",
    "Id": "4"
  },
  {
    "Id": "5"
  },
  {
    "Id": "6"
  },
  {
    "Id": "7"
  },
  {
    "Integration_Status__c": "Pending",
    "Consumed_Date__c": "2022-04-20T14:12:04.000Z",
    "Id": "8"
  }
]
```

I tried something like this, but it is not working:

```
@wire(getData)
    datatable({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            data.forEach((item) => {
                if (typeof item.Integration_Status__c === 'undefined') {
                    item.Integration_Status__c = '';
                }
            });
        } else if (error) { 
            this.errorResponseData = error;
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

The main goal is to show data in datatable.

Comment: Do you want to add the missing elements manually in the javascript? For example - Do you want to add Integration_Status__c as 'None' for id = 2 ?

Comment: Before you pass the array to the datatable within your LWC, you could loop through the array and add missing elements with empty/null/static values and pass the updated array to the datatable. Please add 'what you have tried so far' as part of your question, so community can assist with any blockers/errors you may have within your implementation.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. I updated the question with the piece of code that I tried, but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use below code in the wire function. It uses **nullish coalescing operator** to set default value if the value for that property is null or undefined.

```
@wire(getData)
datatable({ data, error }) {
    if (data && data.length) {
        const newitemlist = [];
        data.forEach(item => {
            var newitem = {
                Integration_Status__c: item.Integration_Status__c ?? '-',
                Consumed_Date__c: item.Consumed_Date__c ?? '-',
                Id: item.Id ?? '-'
            }
            newitemlist.push(newitem);
        });
        this.newDataSet = newitemlist;
    } else if (error) {
        this.errorResponseData = error;
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sneh for your help